# Jetty RewriteRegexRule fail to extract the query string

Tags: java, regex, url-rewriting, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am trying to create a redirect rule to address the following address:

http://localhost/authorize/facebook?code=123456

to

http://localhost/authorize/facebook/123456

To accomplish the requirement, I am using version *9.3.6.v20151106* of **Jetty** and **Jetty Rewrite**. Inside my code, I use the following configuration:

```
    // Rewrite.
    RewriteHandler rewriteHandler = new RewriteHandler();
    rewriteHandler.setOriginalPathAttribute("requestedPath");

    // Rewrite regex rule.
    RewriteRegexRule rewriteRegexRule = new RewriteRegexRule();
    rewriteRegexRule.setRegex("/authorize/([^\\?]+)\\?code=(.*)$");
    rewriteRegexRule.setReplacement("/authorize/$1/$2");
    rewriteHandler.addRule(rewriteRegexRule);

    // Rewrite handler.
    try {
        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{rewriteHandler, webAppContextHandler});
        jettyServer.setHandler(handlers);
```

But, despite the fact its a valid and correct regex pattern, it doesn't match when used with the **Jetty Rewrite**. I've tried to create this pattern incrementally, but it always stop to work when I include *\\?* on the pattern.

May anyone help me  with this rule?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that **RewriteRegexRule** only consider the URL path to match against the regex pattern. To work around this behavior, I've implemented my own regex rule like this:

```
@Override
protected String apply(String target, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Matcher matcher) throws IOException {

    String finalURL = replacement;

    // Replace all $n placeholder by matcher group values.
    for (int index = 1; index <= matcher.groupCount(); index++) {

        String group = matcher.group(index);
        if (group == null) {
            group = new String();
        } else {
            group = Matcher.quoteReplacement(group);
        }

        finalURL = finalURL.replaceAll("\\$" + index, group);
    }

    // Replace all $<parameter> by query string parameters.
    for (String parameterName : request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {

        String parameterValue = (String) request.getParameter(parameterName);
        finalURL = finalURL.replaceAll("\\$" + parameterName, parameterValue);

    }

    return finalURL;

}
```

I was thinking if it could be useful for other people and create a pull request with this contribution to the project. What do you guys think?

Comment: Can you please add the pull request link to your post?